# Draw interactive mandelbrot with pyglet

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyglet, mandelbrot

I have a function that calculates the Mandelbrot set in an numpy array of size (500,500).
I can draw it in matplotlib. Now i want to zoom into the image via mouse click. I want to use pyglet for that but struggle with rendering. I know this (not working) solution is inelegant, so I am happy for advice how to do this better!

PS: The zoom level is set arbitrary right now, my problem I ask for help is the refreshing.

The functions I replaced with a docstring can be found [here](https://github.com/GerJuli/mandelbrot)

```
from pyglet.window import mouse
import pyglet
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from pyglet import image
"""
def calc_pixel_array(x_center: float = 0, y_center: float = 0, 
                     scale: float = 1.0, width: int = 500, 
                     height: int = 500, threshold: int = 200):
    Returns numpy array with shape (500,500) with color values

def plot_pixel_array(pixel_array, cmap: str = 'gnuplot', show_plot: bool = False):
    Draws pixel_array via matplotlib and saves in curent_mandelbrot.png
"""    
pixel_array = calc_pixel_array()
plot_pixel_array(pixel_array)

scale = 1
i = 1
window = pyglet.window.Window(width = 500, height = 500)
image = pyglet.resource.image('curent_mandelbrot.png')
pic = image.load('curent_mandelbrot.png')

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    pic.blit(0, 0)

@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
    if button == mouse.LEFT:
        i = np.random.randint(5)+1
        pixel_array = calc_pixel_array(scale/(10*i))
        plot_pixel_array(pixel_array)
        window.clear()
        image = pyglet.resource.image('curent_mandelbrot.png')
        image.blit(0,0)


pyglet.app.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi after a lot of trying around I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527780/pixelwise-drawing-in-pyglet-python)

```
 def draw_pixel_array(self, window):
        main_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
        shape = self.pixel_array.shape
        for x in range(shape[0]):
            for y in range(shape[1]):
                color = int(self.pixel_array[x, y])
                pyglet.graphics.draw(1, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS,
                                     ('v2i', (x, y)),
                                     ('c3B', (color, color, 0)))
        main_batch.draw()
```

Got it running by removing the on draw and putting everything (calculating and drawing) in the on_mouse_press function.

You will find the complete solution [here](https://github.com/GerJuli/mandelbrot). It is still very slow in drawing, any suggestions there are warmly welcome!